# Does the Ethereum logo have a trademark and can be used on a company-developed app or official website?

Tags: logos

The company's developed APP and official website use Ethereum, can it mark the Ethereum logo?

Comment: That is a legal question. Imho off topic for SO.

Comment: I found this: https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/9w6abe/can_i_use_the_ethereum_logo_on_my_website_the/

Comment: Wrong section; please see: https://law.stackexchange.com/